# Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadioop.io.Text, receiver org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I get error:

> java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadioop.io.Text, receiver org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable

How it is possible with following code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;

public static class RecordMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, DoubleWritable> {

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // ...
            Text newText = new Text(name);
            DoubleWritable newDoubleWritable = new DoubleWritable(newValue); 

            // till now everything is ok

            ctx.write(newText, newDoubleWritable); // ERROR !

            // fails above line
        }
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // ...
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(DoubleWritable.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    // ...
```

Comment: that shouldn't happen actually. sometimes IDE reports wrong things. Try restarting the IDE.

Comment: Show the job definition of the mapper output types

Comment: I run this without IDE... I compile it manually with `javac`. Added job definition of the mapper output types...